# How to Reorganize your private Fiddles

Tags: jsfiddle

On [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), you have your own private Fiddles (on your 'Dashboard'), and you have Public Fiddles.

The Fiddle seems to go Public as soon as it receives a Title.

I want to know the following:

1. **Can I give it a name** or title of some sort, without it having to be public? If so, how?
2. **Can I organize/reorganize** my private Fiddles in any way? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Bit late I know, but I came across the first part of this problem myself today.

In Fiddle Meta, on the left hand side of the fiddle, you can enter a description. This will be displayed under the private fiddle code in your dashboard, so you can keep track of the fiddles.

Don't enter a title in the Meta area, unless you want the fiddle to be made public.

I can't see anyway to re-organise the list of private fiddles, however.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Can I organize/reorganize my private Fiddles in any way? If so, how?

Soon! They have the feature "Grouping fiddles" in the "In development" pane on the roadmap for JSFiddle. Throw the feature a vote and it might come quicker.

"Grouping fiddles" on JSFiddle's official roadmap Trello board: https://trello.com/c/28gPYs4Y/2-grouping-fiddles